# Laravel Seeder is being "killed" while running it on production server, although locally it got executed successfully, any approach on how to fix?

Tags: php, laravel

I am inserting around 2 million records from an excel sheet, separated them to chunks. I added some config lines incase it was a config issue but still same outcome. This is my seeder code. It contains the class that reads the csv file, and the seeder handler. When I run the seeder command on this file, after around 30mins, "killed" is printed on the terminal.

```
class readLargeCSV
{

  public function __construct($filename, $delimiter = "\t")
  {
    $this->file = fopen($filename, 'r');
    $this->delimiter = $delimiter;
    $this->iterator = 0;
    $this->header = null;
  }

  public function csvToArray()
  {
    $data = array();
    while (($row = fgetcsv($this->file, 1000, $this->delimiter)) !== false) {
      $is_mul_1000 = false;
      if (!$this->header) {
        $this->header = $row;
      } else {
        $this->iterator++;
        $data[] = array_combine($this->header, $row);
        if ($this->iterator != 0 && $this->iterator % 1000 == 0) {
          $is_mul_1000 = true;
          $chunk = $data;
          $data = array();
          yield $chunk;
        }
      }
    }
    fclose($this->file);
    if (!$is_mul_1000) {
      yield $data;
    }
    return;
  }
}

class ImportAreasSeeder extends Seeder
{
  /**
   * Run the database seeds.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function run()
  {
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
    DB::connection()->disableQueryLog();

    DB::beginTransaction();

    try {
      $file = base_path("..../cities.csv");
      $csv_reader = new readLargeCSV($file, ",");

      foreach ($csv_reader->csvToArray() as $data) {
        // Preprocessing of the array.
        foreach ($data as $record) {
          DB::table('areas')->insert([
            [
              'name' => $record['name'],
              'zone_id' => ....,
              'country_id' => $record['country_id'],
              'created_at' => ....,
              'updated_at' => ....
            ]
          ]);
        }
      }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
      DB::rollBack();
      throw $e;
    }

    DB::commit();
  }
}
```

Comment: What does "killed" mean? Are you facing any error message? How do you run that seeder?

Comment: You're doing two million rows in one transaction. You probably don't want to be doing that. What exactly does `readLargeCSV` do?

Comment: @NicoHaase I run it using the normal laravel seeder command. Just  "killed" message appears in the terminal after around 20mins of execution.

Comment: @ceejayoz I added the class you mentioned in the code. It just reads the csv file and separate the records into chunks to be inserted in the db.

Comment: @RaedN Can you commit every 10k lines or so? Can you use bulk inserts instead of a query per row? (You're already using the right function, `insert()`, but you're only ever giving it one row at a time...)

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes I fixed the structure to insert 1000 rows at once. Although it gave me a memory allocation error, the seed was successful and data was inserted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care about data exists in table ( you truncate first), maybe another solution is more suitable.

For `mysql`: ([load data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html))

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/cities.csv' 
INTO TABLE discounts 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

For `postgresql`: ([copy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html))

```
COPY country FROM '/path/to/cities.csv';
```

PS: Another option is to create a `temporary table`
load `csv` in this and move data to original table with `insert into ... select ...`

Answer (score -1):

Please try this. it should work for you

when your csv file large we want to add enough memory limit to server. if it is not enough script will fail. so you can use like this

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); // 0 = Unlimited
ini_set('memory_limit','5G');
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What makes you think that this resolves the given problem? Is this a pure guess, or do you know why the execution was "killed"?

Comment: Ok sure. i will do it next time

Comment: "if it is not enough script will fail" - will it? Shouldn't such a Seeder class run on the shell, where the max_execution_time isn't even used in the default configuration?

Comment: @ChamindaChanaka The scripts you mentioned are already written in the code but same outcome,

Comment: @NicoHaase Do you have any suggesion for him

Comment: That depends on more details the OP should share in the initial post

Comment: @NicoHaase normally when we run script we can use like this. normally im using it. it is worked for me. that is why i suggest that

Comment: If the OP tells you this approach is already in the script (or any other configuration), but it's not working, then I would assume that this is not a proper solution for the given problem

Comment: you save my time my bro. thank you so much in my server everything killed